# gcc-8 Wstringop-truncation

Tags: c, gcc, strncpy, gcc8

I'm trying to fix some C code where gcc-8 complains about Wstringop-truncation (code is [here](https://github.com/bnosac/crfsuite/blob/master/src/cqdb/src/cqdb.c))

When compiling that code on a server which I can not control neither can add pragma statements nor can disable Wstringop-truncation diagnostics, the warning which I receive is:

```
gcc-8  -I"/home/hornik/tmp/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./cqdb/include -I./crf/src -I./liblbfgs/include -I./include -I"/home/hornik/lib/R/Library/3.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native -c cqdb/src/cqdb.c -o cqdb/src/cqdb.o
cqdb/src/cqdb.c: In function ‘cqdb_writer_close’:
cqdb/src/cqdb.c:270:5: warning: ‘strncpy’ output truncated before terminating nul copying 4 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
     strncpy((char*)header.chunkid, CHUNKID, 4);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cqdb/src/cqdb.c: In function ‘cqdb_reader’:
cqdb/src/cqdb.c:469:9: warning: ‘strncpy’ specified bound 4 equals destination size [-Wstringop-truncation]
         strncpy((char*)db->header.chunkid, (const char*)p, 4);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I would like to rewrite the strncpy statements to remove these warnings. Am I right that I need to replace in the following lines

```
strncpy((char*)header.chunkid, CHUNKID, 4);
with strncpy((char*)header.chunkid, CHUNKID, 5);

and strncpy((char*)db->header.chunkid, (const char*)p, 4);
with strncpy((char*)db->header.chunkid, (const char*)p, 5);
```

The relevant code in cqdb.c is put below. It basically checks if the file is of type 'CQDB'. 
Mark that although I would really love to have access, I do not have access to this machine so I can not test out if the fixes to the C code will work.

```
#define CHUNKID             "CQDB"

typedef struct {
    int8_t      chunkid[4]; /**< Chunk identifier, "CQDB". */
    uint32_t    size;       /**< Chunk size including this header. */
    uint32_t    flag;       /**< Global flags. */
    uint32_t    byteorder;  /**< Byte-order indicator. */
    uint32_t    bwd_size;   /**< Number of elements in the backward array. */
    uint32_t    bwd_offset; /**< Offset to the backward array. */
} header_t;

int cqdb_writer_close(cqdb_writer_t* dbw)
{
header_t header;
strncpy((char*)header.chunkid, CHUNKID, 4);
...
}

cqdb_t* cqdb_reader(const void *buffer, size_t size)
{
    cqdb_t* db = NULL;
    /* Check the file chunkid. */
    if (memcmp(buffer, CHUNKID, 4) != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    db = (cqdb_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(cqdb_t));
    const uint8_t* p = NULL;
    db->buffer = buffer;
    p = db->buffer;
    strncpy((char*)db->header.chunkid, (const char*)p, 4);
...
}
```

Comment: How is it that you can edit the code but not add pragmas?

Comment: I'm not allowed to add pragma's, it's an R package wrapping C++ code, the CRAN policy distributing R packages disallows setting specific pragma's. Thank you for the memcpy suggestion, I'll look into the docs of that.

Comment: You definitely do not want to try copying 5 bytes into a 4-byte buffer as you suggest

Comment: Are you writing C or C++?  You've tagged the question C++, but the code you posted is all C code.

Comment: "I would like to rewrite the strncpy statements to remove these warnings" (followed by subtly but tragically breaking changes) - [surely gives me some deja vu...](https://research.swtch.com/openssl) Please, do not _ever_ try to "fix" warnings without fully understanding what you are doing; you risk introducing way worse problems than some garbage in console when compiling.

Comment: That is exactly the reason way I am asking here.

Comment: Use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` instead of `strncpy()` when you definitely won't copy the null byte from the source string.  It might even be faster, but it fixes the warnings.  It's basically what M.M suggests in their answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if the code needs to cope with strings that might be shorter than 4 then you'd need to take care

Comment: @M.M — you always need to take care. :D . You're right, but the compile won't gripe if the literal )including the null terminator) is not longer than the length specified.  That is, the compiler won't generate a warning for the case where extra care must be taken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usage of `strncpy` in the question is actually correct (left-justifying some characters in a buffer, right-padding with null bytes), but the warning is because this function is often misused by people trying to copy a null-terminated string.

For the code shown in the question I would replace the `strncpy` calls with:

```
set_chunkid(&header);
```

where you add a new function:

```
void set_chunkid(header_t *hdr)
{
    _Static_assert(sizeof CHUNKID == sizeof hdr->chunkid + 1, "chunk ID not 4 chars");

    memcpy(&hdr->chunkid, CHUNKID, sizeof hdr->chunkid);
}
```

If there are other use cases that this function doesn't cover then update the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, will try it out.